# How to make second div move to next line when browser resized

Tags: css, crm, osc

I have 2 divs side by side and I want my second div to move down below of 1st div when browser is resized or viewed in mobile phones.

Here's the website: 
https://zte-iqorsupport.custhelp.com/

The divs that have issue are rn_PageContent and rn_SideBar

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: Please re-read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for a media query.

```
@media (max-width: 640px) {
  rn_PageContent, rn_SideBar {
    float: none;
    clear: both;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Remove **float:right** from rn_SideBar

Comment: Hello, tried it but it automatically goes to the next line even in normal size of the browser. :(

Comment: Have a look at how to make a div responsive. And make the container div a responsive one.